# Множество POST запросов

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Мне нужно создать в пользовательском справочнике допустим 1000 объектов. Сейчас одним запросом создается один объект, соответственно это дело занимает много времени. Может есть какой-то иной путь?

Comment: Может создать за раз нужное количество объектов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-post) не приведено массовое создание объектов в пользовательском справочнике, но при запросе

```
  curl -X POST \
  https://online-18.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customentity/{your_entity_id} \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_AUTH' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: POSTMAN_TOKEN' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '[
    {
        "name": "world"
    },
    {
        "name": "another world"
    }
]'
```

можно создать множество объектов в справочнике. Можно посмотреть как аналогично происходит массовое создание [в других сущностях](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-post).